# Entity Framework 7 FromSql stored procedure return value

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I am trying to return a value using the new `FromSql` command in Entity Framework 7. My stored procedure returns a value of 0 if all goes well and 1 if an error occurs.

Using `FromSql` with `DbSet` we can for example do

```
_dbContext.ExampleEntity.FromSql('someSproc', 'param')
```

How will you get the scalar return value of 0 or 1 from this?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like stored procedure support is [still on the backlog](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/245).

Here's an example extension method you can call using `_dbContext.ExecuteStoredProcedure("someSproc", "param");`.

```
public static class DbContextExtension 
{
    public static int ExecuteStoredProcedure(this DbContext context, string name, string parameter)
    {
        var command = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = name;
        var param = command.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@p0";
        param.Value = parameter;
        command.Parameters.Add(param);
        return (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Stafford, that looks spot on for what I need.  Question, how do you get/instantiate the context in the first place in order to be able to call the extension method above?

Comment: @mattpm depends on how your application is setup.  Start here; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext

Comment: This does not work for me - I get "ExecuteScalar requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed."  In order to get it to work I have to explicitly open the connection, as shown here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/39543702/432085.  I am injecting my DbContext via the Startup.cs in an ASP.Net Core API, and I have no issues with other DbContext operations.  Would be curious to know how you got this to work.