# Is it possible to execute custom SQL query using EF7

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I decided to move one of my projects to Entity Framework 7 (rc1-final). I am targeting SQL Server and `EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer` package is also installed.

I have only one problem: it seems like I can't execute custom SQL query in order to fetch some objects from DB.

`DatabaseFacade` object (which can be accessed via `DbContext.Database` property) provides an extension method `ExecuteSqlCommand` (that returns nothing), But it does not provide `SqlQuery<T>` method that allows to fetch objects. Both methods were available in good old EF 6, but new EF 7 declares only first one.

So, is `SqlQuery<T>` method still here (but moved/renamed) or it was entirely removed from new EF implementation?

Of course it is absolutely possible to solve it in a verbose way (using `SqlCommand` and its `ExecuteReader` method) but I prefer to avoid it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`EntityFramework.Relational`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/EntityFramework.Relational/RelationalQueryableExtensions.cs) exposes the following extension method;

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> FromSql<TEntity>(
        [NotNull] this IQueryable<TEntity> source,
        [NotNull] [NotParameterized] string sql,
        [NotNull] params object[] parameters)
        where TEntity : class
```

So you can do this;

```
myDatabaseContext.Customers.FromSql("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Name='p0'", "timothy");
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know about that method already, but, unfortunately it needs IQueryable<T> as input parameter. As I understand that method should be used together with some DbSet<T> that, in turn, should be defined inside DbContext. My case is little different - I want to get objects which not present in my DbContext (i.e. just execute query and create object of type T for each returned row).

Comment: In that case just use the underlying SqlCommand like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34191033/469777).

Comment: Actually I am using that approach now (Command + ExecuteReader). It is verbose in compare with missing SqlQuery<T>, but it, of course, works. Btw, thank you for your time and for your answer - it is definitely useful - appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

To execute a custome SQL query in EF7, you can create a "fake" table which structure like structure of your SQL query returns.

***Example:*** Your query is: *"select a.A, b.B from A,B where a.b_id=b.id"*. The fake table will contain 2 column like A,B. 
In your program, you can do this:

```
var result = myDatabaseContext.FakeTables.FromSql("select a.A, b.B from A,B where a.b_id=b.id");
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use the Sql method on the migrationBuilder object that is passed into the Up and Down methods. At least in rc2.

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    ...
    migrationBuilder.Sql("<Sql here>");
}
```

Comment: This method 'migrationBuilder.Sql' doesn't seem to exist in the EF Core RTM version. Anyone know of the equivalent?